# mongodb: restrict read/write access on a specific collection

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way that we can restrict the read/write access for a specific collection in a DB even though users have the read/write access for the Database ?

For example: I have a DB called : PRODCAST and it contains collA, collB, collC and collD. Assume that we have 10 users where they all can able to access the PRODCAST database and able to perform the read/write operations on all collections which are existed in the DB.

Here my question is, Is there anyway we can prevent all the users to perform read/write operations especially on **CollC** as the collC having some sensitive data hence i would not show to everyone even though they have the DB access.

Comment: The simplest way probably would be to not have collC in that database. As to your question, [Mongodb Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/) appears to be flexible enough to work on collection level. I personally haven't used it, though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Thanks for you comment. In fact i too preferred to keep it the collC in a separate DB,  but eventually the other DB would not only the collC, there may be some other collections too. Since the other collection were crated by someone else then definitely they would have the access the other DB and they also can able to see the collC sensitive data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way that we can restrict the read/write access for a specific collection in a DB even though users have the read/write access for the Database ?

As at MongoDB 3.6, roles and privileges are additive: you can grant additional permissions to a user but cannot remove or restrict existing privileges that have been granted or inherited.

> For example: I have a DB called : PRODCAST and it contains collA, collB, collC and collD. Assume that we have 10 users where they all can able to access the PRODCAST database and able to perform the read/write operations on all collections which are existed in the DB.

Suggested approaches to restrict access to `collC` would be to either:

- explicitly [grant permission for each collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/) (instead of read/write access for the entire `PRODCAST` database), or
- create a separate database for collections needing more restrictive permissions

If all of your users need a common set of access privileges you could create a [user-defined (custom) role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/) to make administration easier. You could then [grant the custom role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/) (eg. `PRODCAST`) to your users and update the role as required when you add new collections/databases with shared access.

> Here my question is, Is there anyway we can prevent all the users to perform read/write operations especially on **CollC** as the collC having some sensitive data hence i would not show to everyone even though they have the DB access.

For further restrictions on accessing sensitive data, you could use either of the above approaches to limit overall read/write access and then create a [read-only view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) of the collection (MongoDB 3.4+). Similar to collections, access to views requires read access. However, read permission to a view can be granted without read permission to the underlying collection, so sensitive fields can be fully redacted.

Comment: Thanks for sharing diff options. It would be really helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: can you touch more on how to grant specific permissions on a collection for a user?  I want my user to be able to read, insert and update on specific collections and only read on another set of collections.