# Block creation or usage of *specific* collections in Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a python project with many calls from multiple places and services to a specific mongo collection - lets call it "cache_collection".
I moved this collection to a different Mongo instance to reduce load from the major db, and plan to remove the collection in the older db.

The thing is this - I want to make sure it won't be possible to access "cache_collection" in the older db. meaning calling get_collection('cache_collection') will return an exception, or any attempt to read/write from this collection will raise an exception. Since mongo dynamically generates collections per demand, the desired behavior is not that easy to get.

I've read about [Mongo access-control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/) and [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436041/mongodb-restrict-read-write-access-on-a-specific-collection) but it's not ideal. because it seems like permissions are additive and not restrictive and I don't want to define the "basic" permission set as none and keep maintaining collection permissions for the rest of the project.

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: Just pondering, ... I wonder what would happen if you created  `cache_collection` in the older db with ridiculous/onerous/restrictive/strict validation rules that would produce errors, and maybe even only return a document with a message to use the new db/collection.  Or maybe restrict on the Python side, i.e., use crafted library calls that wouldn't accept the `cache_collection` as a source or destination collection.